# Streaming with a Sony NX5

Tags: live, video, mac, streaming

I recently obtained a Sony NX5, now aside from the fact that its pretty much a great camera in every way (afaik); it doesn't have a IEEE 1394 port. I assume this is probably related to the AVCHD format that the NX5 uses.

Regardless, I can't find an easy way to stream with it on to the Macs I've been given. Up to this point it's been fine as I've only needed to get the footage post-shoot. But next week I've got an event coming up and they want to use the NX5 to stream the footage from on-site to a synchronous event occurring elsewhere.

Their ambitions are high, but I figured if I can get the stream from the camera to the Mac, then I should be able to hook it up to the live stream.

Anyone got any pointers/hints/tips on how I can do this?

Comment: Analog to digital converter and then FW in to mac from there.